# How Lucene search works?

Tags: lucene

I'm testing Lucene indexing/searchin and I have a doubt. To test I create some simple files. 
Example:

**mark_test_mark.txt**

mark test mark

**a.txt**

mark
test
mark
mark
test
mark
mark
test
mark
mark
test
mark

---

I extrac the files' content and I'm indexing this too. 
I'm creating the document to indexing this way:

```
doc.add(new Field(FILE_NAME, index.getFileName().trim(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED, Field.TermVector.YES));
doc.add(new Field(FILE_NAME_LOWER, index.getFileName().toLowerCase().trim(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED, Field.TermVector.YES));
doc.add(new Field(CONTENT, index.getFileContent(), Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED, Field.TermVector.YES));
```

My question is when I do a seach for a keyword like 'mark'.
Lucene returns to me the following result:

```
mark_test_mark.txt  -> 0.36452034 

a.txt   -> 0.36452034
```

Where, the 1st part represent the file name, and the second, the search score.

In my opinion, these 2 files don't have the same score and the first file should be a.txt.

Am I wrong?

EDIT:
I forget to say that I'm searching by name and content, so I do a multi-field search.
I'm using this code to do this:

```
IndexReader reader = IndexReader.open(Indexer.getFSDirectory(searchDirectory));

IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);

Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_36);

MultiFieldQueryParser queryParser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(Version.LUCENE_36, new String[] {Indexer.FILE_NAME_LOWER, Indexer.CONTENT}, analyzer);

TopDocs topDocs = null;

try {
    topDocs = searcher.search(queryParser.parse(searchQuery.getQuery()), getHitsPerPage());

} catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();

}

ScoreDoc[] hits = topDocs.scoreDocs;
```

Comment: You could make this question a little bit more constructive by explaining why you think the score should be different? In my opinion,  the number of `marks` to total text ratio is identical in both exemples, so it seems normal that it have the same weight.

Comment: In the 1sh file there are 4 'mark': 2 in the title and 2 in the content.

In the 2sh, there are 8 'mark': all of this in the content

The ratio is NOT identical

Comment: The score uses the Inverse Document Frequency (across the document collection) and this is why it is the same.

Comment: Ok. I get it.

Is there any way to return the documents ordered by the number of matches?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12586585/finding-total-number-of-matches-to-a-query-with-lucene) might help.

Comment: I think the main score elements impacting this are probably `coord` (1 match in each field above 2 matches in body), which favors having matches on more query terms, and `lengthnorm`, which favors matches in shorter fields. `idf` will have some impact on favoring matches on the title field, but it should be light, compared to those factors. [IndexSearcher.explain](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_5_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/IndexSearcher.html#explain(org.apache.lucene.search.Weight,%20int)) would show you what factors the scores you are seeing are based on.